# WordPress admin hangs on MAMP 4 and macOS Sierra

Tags: wordpress, macos, curl, mamp, macos-sierra

Since I updated to macOS Sierra and MAMP 4 the WordPress admin hangs before loading. This only happens on a dashboard and updates page. The page takes about 1 minute to load and displays the following error on top:

> An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums.

The updates page shows the same error and always claims everything is up do date, unless I click the "Check Again" button in which case it will also append the following information:

> WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.

So apparently outgoing HTTPS requests are not resolving.

Adding this line to wp-config.php makes the error go away but I am no longer notified of core and plugin updates:

```
define('WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', true);
```

Not sure if the problem is related to MAMP 4 or macOS Sierra since I updated both at the same time.

I have updated from Yosemite directly to Sierra and found that the new OS uses its proprietary SecureTransport protocol instead of OpenSSL when sending a cURL to a secure connection, though from what I can tell MAMP bypasses this and uses its own compiled OpenSSL:

```
$ php -i | grep "SSL Version"
```

prints this:

```
SSL Version => SecureTransport
```

and

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.12/bin/php -i | grep "SSL Version"
```

prints this:

```
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.2j
```

I'm using Apache, have no vhosts and the behavior is the same with mod_ssl disabled or enabled. I have even self-signed a certificate and authorized it through KeyChain to use it with mod_ssl and the behavior didn't change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing mamp 4?